# If I use two EC2 instances each in a given region, will I be charged?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently deployed a Java application to the Elastic Beanstalk service. I saw that when creating an environment, an EC2 instance was also generated by Elastic Beanstalk. Now, I would like to create another instance to host my project in Angular, however, I think I will be charged since in the free plan the user only has 750 free hours to use, which means that having two instances I will be charged from of 15 days...
If I create two instances, each in a certain region, is it possible to work around this situation and not be charged, so that I use 750 of each instance?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, free tier billing is consolidated through regions:

> **Q: Can I use the AWS Free Tier in any region?**
>
> The AWS Free Tier applies to participating services across our global
> regions. Your free usage under the AWS Free Tier is calculated each
> month across all regions and automatically applied to your bill. ***For
> example, you will receive 750 Amazon EC2 Linux Micro Instance hours
> for free across all of the regions you use, not 750 hours per region***.
> Source: https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier-faqs/

Anyway, if your Angular application is simply a static website, you can host it on S3, with no additional charges (S3 have 5GB of storage in the free tier).
See also: [Hosting a static website using S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html).

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to enable HTTPS using S3?

Comment: Yeah, sure, S3 have https enabled by default.

Comment: I'm adding in the answer the documentation on how to use S3 to host a static website.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bruna Also you can use Amazon Lightsail service free of charge for 3months (750 hrs/month) just incase if you want to use it for test purpose.

Comment: @Vishal Good to know. Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely give this service a look.